# How to locate the element using selenium-webdriver and Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

How can I call xpath for `class`?

`<button class="inline" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-11310="11310">Load</button>`

I tried to to call it by :

```
By.xpath("//span/button[text()='Load'][1]");
```

but it is not able to locate element.

Comment: you can add the error or exception your getting as well for better answers.

Comment: `//button[@class='inline' and text()='Load']`

Answer (score 1):

Use this xpath:

```
//button[@class='inline' and text()='Load']
```

Answer (score 0):

The element seems to be a [Ember.js](https://www.emberjs.com/) enabled element so to `click()` on the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *elementToBeClickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("button.inline[data-ember-action]"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@class='inline' and text()='Load'][@data-ember-action]"))).click();
  ```